# Understanding the Recent Controversies

Tags: support

Someone, please explain like I'm 5.

I understand there has been a lot of uproar in the community recently, regarding the firing of the community moderator, Monica, and some general dissent among the StackOverflow users particularly.

I've read a bunch of articles about this, but I'm unable to fully understand this issue. As a StackOverflow contributor myself, I feel I should be aware of all this, but I must admit I haven't been too active on Meta.

Can someone please explain why many users are announcing that they won't be contributing to SO anymore? **People are still asking questions**, and as far as I know, their questions still need answering. How will leaving this site help anybody, and how does the Monica incident tie in with this?

Comment: TL;DR: users have started to distrust the company due to its recent actions and aren't feeling like contributing their time to a platform owned by an untrustworthy company.

Comment: *"questions still need answering"* — It's not like that's anyone's job or responsibility per se…

Comment: [A general introduction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper).

Comment: It is about money.  Rather a lot of it.  Any speculation about it sounds like a crazy conspiracy theory, so site-owners and community members keep bringing up unrelated issues to demonstrate their goals are not the same.

Comment: **You can start [here](https://stackexchange-timeline.webflow.io/#the-welcoming) and read upwards.** Some things are always going to be missing. E.g. when SO changed its homepage for anonymous users from.

Comment: "How will leaving this site help anybody..." Typically, the rationale for leaving a place is not becoming totally inactive but remaining active, only somewhere else. Leaving might mean being able to help somewhere else. The people asking questions could probably also ask them somewhere else, if necessary. Now I don't know exactly where this somewhere else is or if it even exists but I guess that it would make an interesting question.

Comment: To provide a broader base (i.e. another voice): For me, it's pretty much what deceze writes in the first comment about trust. It feels like the company keeps pulling the rug out from under one's feet. Every time one starts to believe things have settled down, something else happens, and the rules keep changing. Then there's the impression that there's nothing to stop "them" from doing to anyone what was done to Monica (public libel). And the concern the site is turning into a "anything goes help desk" where unpaid professionals are doing the work and others rake in the $$$.

Comment: Thanks a ton everybody! I've checked out all these links, and I think I'm much better informed about this whole situation (as I should have been) :)

Comment: My take: many long time users felt they shared a certain understanding with SO the company about the goals and values of the project. A number of pretty dramatic actions in the last year or so have led to many people reaching the upsetting conclusion that this was no longer true, and they felt betrayed and hurt, and angry, and the company has done very little to make any of this better, so they have left.

Comment: It's not that the company has done little to make things better. More like they did everything in their power to make things worse. And to be very clear: there have been repercussions. The answer rate has [dropped by almost 10%](https://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/how_sjws_affected_stack_overflow.shtml) as a direct result. Just in case someone was still operating under the delusion that high profile users leaving wouldn't matter. I for one decided to set up [my own forum](https://ask.planetcobalt.net/). Not as sophisticated as SO, but mine. If anyone is interested: feel free to join.